# Open Random Post Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want my code when someone clicks the link then a link will open random of 3 posts between `*/android.html` ,`*/samsung.html` and `*/xiaomi.html`.

My code is like this

```
<?php 
$YuuClass->update_dls($file['downloads'], $file_id);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+ 1);
var xxx=null;
if(x=="1"){xxx="android.html"}
if(x=="2"){xxx="samsung.html"}
if(x=="3"){xxx="xiaomi.html"}
</script>';
redirect('https://safelink-ainodorama.blogspot.com/2017/02/"+xxx+"?url='.base64_encode($copy['webContentLink']));
exit();
?>
```

Where `"+xxx+"` will change random between `*/android.html` ,`*/samsung.html` and `*/xiaomi.html` when I click it.

I tried to click it with code like that only showing base64code.

Ex-link when I click

`http://myweb.web.id/0aHR0cHM6Ly9kcml2ZS5nb29nbGUuY29tL2Evc2RuMTgzcGVrYW5iYXJ1LnNjaC5pZC91Yz9pZD0xMUNoa0JpS3lvWkRMMGIxTWxYek4yeUt2NGRQcnJoMG8mZXhwb3J0PWRvd25sb2Fk`

I want when I click it the URL will be like this
`https://safelink-ainodorama.blogspot.com/2017/02/android.html?url=base64_code_here`

where android.html can change randomly from 2 another page android, Samsung and Xiaomi.

Comment: Where did `redirect();` come from? I'll assume thats a custom function you have somewhere.

Comment: @Randall I presumed that too, same for `$YuuClass`,`$copy`, `$file`, `$file_id`.

Comment: It had me digging through the php.net site to see if a function existed as a shorthand for `header('Location: http://blahblahblah');` lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because javascript is client-side and php is server-side the javascript wont change `xxx`.

Instead have an array of your pages, then use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to pick a random one.

**Something like:**

```
<?php 
$YuuClass->update_dls($file['downloads'], $file_id);

$page = [
    'android.html',
    'samsung.html',
    'xiaomi.html'
];

$url = 'https://safelink-ainodorama.blogspot.com/2017/02/'.$page[array_rand($page)].'?url='.base64_encode($copy['webContentLink']);

redirect($url);
exit;
```